# Kinsoku Shori breaking multiple times in a single paragraph

Tags: luatex, line-breaking, japanese, luatexja

Unfortunately I can't provide the main text I'm facing problems with (far more than the sample) due to copyright issues, but even in this sample you can see multiple lines broken. I would rather have a bit of hoverflow than unrecognizable lines and paragraphs. Is there anything I could do? (it might be worth mentioning that I always get tons of warnings from luatexja, but I do have all the required packages and such, not sure if it's related.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{ltjreport}
\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{luatexja-preset}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{japanese}

\begin{document}
復帰後のナリタブライアンの体調については、万全ではないという判断が多くなされた。大川慶次郎は天皇賞（秋）の後、厩舎において同馬を見た際の印象として「整体が狂っている、それもかなり重症ではないか」[51]、「肉がまったくなく、全盛期を100とすれば60か70」[52]と評価した。大川は、ナリタブライアンの体調が引退するまでに故障前の状態に戻ることは無かったと述べている。岡部幸雄は天皇賞（秋）出走時の状態について「全然、覇気がなかった」と評している[53]。また、ジャパンカップにおいてランドに騎乗したマイケル・ロバーツは「私の記憶している全盛期のナリタブライアンではなかった」とコメントした[54][55]。天皇賞（秋）から有馬記念にかけてのレース振りについて、的場均と武豊はともに「途中まではいい感じだったが、直線で止まってしまった」とコメントした[56]。
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which TeX distribution, which version of LuaTeX, and which versions of the `fontspec` and `polyglossia` packages do you employ? For what it's worth, on my system -- MacTeX2019, LuaTeX 1.10.0, luatexja-fontspec 2019/09/26, fontspec 2019/10/19 v2.7d, and polyglossia 2019/11/15 v1.46 -- I am unable to reproduce the line-breaking issues you report when I compile your test program. The font employed by the test program was found at `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/ipaex/ipaexm.ttf`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you! I'm using the MikTex distribution, `luatexja` being from 20191118.0, `lualatex` being 1.11.2 and `fontspec` being 2.7d (`polyglossia` doesn't seem to make any difference). Interestingly though, using a much older version based on TexLive I can't reproduce the issue myself either. I even tried the ipaex font on my MikTex setup, with no difference.

Comment: You may want to contact the maintainer(s) of the ltjreport class and bring your posting to their attention, in particular to mention that there's a divergence between the outputs of TeXLive and MikTeX.

Comment: @Mico I installed a newer version of TexLive in the exact system and there are no such problems. I will file a bug report on OSDN.

Comment: Glad you were able to set up a system that works. I'm going to suggest to close this posting, not because it's not a good posting, but because it got resolved via the comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the issue raised by the OP has been determined to be caused by what's likely to be a bug and because the OP reports having found a satisfactory work-around.